# What part of my code is causing an Undefined Index error? (PHP)

Tags: php, mysqli, forum

I am working on a small forum and I am currently trying to display the forum topics in a separate file. For whatever reason when I open the file it is displaying these errors:

> Notice: Undefined index: cid in C:\xampp\htdocs(A)Book 2.0\Bootstrap\topics.php on line 19
>
> Notice: Undefined index: scid in C:\xampp\htdocs(A)Book
>   2.0\Bootstrap\topics.php on line 20
>
> Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result,
>   boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs(A)Book
>   2.0\Bootstrap\content_function.php on line 41

I've tried to use an isset function for the variables, but it hasn't worked. I'm calling the variables from a separate functions file.

Here's the code displaying the topics:

```
    <?php
session_start();
require_once ('../db.php');

// Check if user is logged in using the session variable
if ( $_SESSION['logged_in'] != 1 ) {
  $_SESSION['message'] = "You must log in before viewing your profile page!";
  header("location: error.php");
  exit; //<--- add this
}else {
    // Makes it easier to read
    $first_name = $_SESSION['first_name'];
    $last_name = $_SESSION['last_name'];
    $email = $_SESSION['email'];
    $active = $_SESSION['active'];
}

include ('content_function.php');
$cid2 = $_GET['cid'];
$scid2 = $_GET['scid'];
 ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
<head>
  <title>Topics</title>
  <link href="main.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
<div class = "content">
  <?php
  /*
  $select = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM categories");
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select)){
    echo  "<h1>", $row['category_title']."</h1>" ;
  }*/

  disptopics($cid2, $scid2, $mysqli);
  /*if (isset($_GET['cid'], $GET['scid'])){

    disptopics();
  }*/

   ?>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Also, here is the code for the functions:

```
    <?php
require '../db.php';
  function dispcategories($mysqli){
    $select = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM categories");

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select)){
      echo "<table class = 'category-table'";
      echo "<tr><td class= 'main-category'colspan='2'>".$row['category_title']."</tr></td>";
      dispsubcategories($row['cat_id'], $mysqli);
      echo "</table>";
    }
  }

  function dispsubcategories($parent_id, $mysqli){
    $select = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT cat_id, subcat_id, subcategory_title, subcategory_descr FROM categories, subcategories
                                     WHERE ($parent_id = categories.cat_id) AND ($parent_id = subcategories.parent_id)");
    echo "<tr><th width='90%'>Categories</th><th width='10%'>Topics</th></tr>";

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select)){
      echo "<tr><td class='category_title'><a href='topics.php/".$row['cat_id']."/".$row['subcat_id']."'>
                    ".$row['subcategory_title']."<br/>";
      echo $row['subcategory_descr']."</a></td>";
      echo "<td class='num-topics'>".getnumtopics($parent_id, $row['subcat_id'], $mysqli)."</td></tr>";
    }
  }
  //Displays categories
  function getnumtopics($cat_id, $subcat_id, $mysqli){
    $select = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT category_id, subcategory_id FROM topics WHERE ".$cat_id." = category_id
                    AND ".$subcat_id." = subcategory_id");
$get = mysqli_num_rows($select);

return $get;
  }
  //Displays Topics Within categories
  function disptopics($cid, $scid, $mysqli){
    $select = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT topic_id, author, title, date_posted, views, replies FROM categories, subcategories, topics
                                     WHERE ($cid = topics.category_id) AND ($scid = topics.subcategory_id) AND ($cid = categories.cat_id)
                                     AND ($scid = subcategories.subcat_id) ORDER BY topic_id DESC");


   if(mysqli_num_rows($select) != 0) {
      echo "<table class='topic-table'>";
      echo "<tr><th>Title</th><th>Posted By</th><th>Date Posted</th><th>Views</th><th>Replies</th></tr>";

      while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select)){
        echo "<tr><td><a href='readtopic.php/".$cid."/".$scid."/".$row['topic_id']."'>
              ".$row['title']."</a></td><td>".$row['author']."</td><td>".$row['date-posted'].".</td><td>".$row['views']."</td>
              <td>".$row['replies']."</td></tr>";
      }
      echo "</table>";
    } else {
      echo "<p>This category has no topics yet! <a href='newtopic.php/".$cid."/".$scid."'> Add a new one!</a></p>";
    }

  }


?>
```

I've looked over each file multiple times and used a code checker that says I have no syntax errors.

Comment: You need to test if `$_GET['cid']` and `$_GET['scid']` is set or not empty before using it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undef)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$_GET` is an array, and if the user haven't defined a `scid=something` in the query string, then `$_GET['scid']` is undefined. There, you got an undefined index Notice.

You should test if `isset($_GET['scid'])` before trying to read it's value.

Comment: Is it not defined under the distopics() function?

Comment: @CaptainAmerica16 Well, I'd say evidence says it's not.

Comment: I just entered                                                                       
  if(isset($_GET['scid'])){
    echo "It works";
  }                                                                                                                                     but nothing printed out.

Comment: @CaptainAmerica16 That proves what we already know, the index is not defined.

Comment: I'm new to PHP so sorry if I'm being a little slow. Could you give me an example of how to define it? I have ($scid = topics.subcategory_id) AND ($scid = subcategories.subcat_id) in my function file. I'm not sure what it is I'm doing wrong.

Comment: @CaptainAmerica16 In order to `$_GET['scid']` to be defined, the user must call the page like `page.php?scid=value` , this will define `$_GET['scid']` to `value`. If `isset($_GET['scid'])` is true, then this happened, otherwise `$_GET['scid']` is undefined and you probably should default `$scid` to `0` or perhaps tell the user an error occurred because no `scid` was specified.

Comment: @CaptainAmerica16 You can do that inline with `$scid = isset($_GET['scid']) ? $_GET['scid'] : 0;`

Comment: @CaptainAmerica16 Another thing that you should be very careful is to filter `$scid` so the user cannot set it to any arbitrary value it is not supposed to. Remember you are injecting `$scid` directly into a SQL query, and if the user is allowed to put anything he wants there, you have a [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)  problem.

Answer (score 0):

from where this $_GET['cid'] and $_GET['scid'] is getting data please check echo $_GET['cid'] or you also do var_dump($_GET);